# Cucumber Issue - Method 'find_by_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

Implementing my step definition according to my user story, I wanted to fill a form to instantiate a new user.

I tried a couple of method, `find_by_id`, `find("#user_display_name").set("name")`, and `fill_in "user_display_name", with: "Name"`, but all of them could not find my input that indeed exist and is visible. 
[here is the wanted element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnjM3.png)

Here is the error that I got `Unable to find visible id "user_display_name" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`

Does anyone please know how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be a nice guy and use labels instead of [placeholder disease](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/). It will not only be accessible to users that rely on assistive technology but it will also let you write `fill_in "Display name", with: "Merry Poppins"`.

Comment: Oh, will do then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my dilemma. That was a simple case of un-seeded db for the test. See, I thought that having an up and running app with real data was enough to run my tests. Then I realized, that I needed to seed before any test as it initialize the environement. Now, I can use `find_by_id`.